# Finding function which hearts performance in react native and chrome debuger

Tags: react-native, google-chrome

what's the best way to find a function which takes most cpu and memory in react native app? I tried chrome devtools -> performance, but out put just tells me that function was executed, without name of function and proper stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug with the help of  android studio and Xcode

check the memory  [As explained here](https://blog.swmansion.com/hunting-js-memory-leaks-in-react-native-apps-bd73807d0fde)[and here](https://shift.infinite.red/react-native-android-app-memory-investigation-55695625da9c)

And CPU utilization
With [this tool](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) as explained in 
[the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#profiling)

Comment: Interesting. Can you give me more details on how can I see which javascript function takes most cpu and memory for certain period?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler

Comment: https://blog.swmansion.com/hunting-js-memory-leaks-in-react-native-apps-bd73807d0fde

Comment: just viewed the post it talks about memory leaks, while I need to detect cpu usage . and time it took to execute functions. any ideas?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#profiling